# Nodejs - TypeError stating that the hashPassword function is not a function, how can I solve it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, authentication

how is everything ? I really need your help!

I'm building an API to register authenticated users, with storage in the mongo atlas database (cloud). I'm currently experiencing the following error: `TypeError subscription error: User.hashPassword is not a function`. I've done several researches, in several questions here on stackoverflow and on other sites, after testing all the solutions the error persists.

my `user.model.js` file looks like this:

```
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");
    const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

    const userSchema = new Schema(
        {
            userName: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
            email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
            emailToken: { type: String, default: null },
            emailTokenExpires: { type: Date, default: null },
            active: { type: Boolean, default: false},
            password: { type: String, required: true},
            resetPasswordToken: { type: String, default: null },
            resetPasswordExpires: { type: Date, default: null },
            emailToken: {type: String, default: null}, 
            emailTokenExpires: {type: Date, default: null},
        },
        {
            timestamps: {
                createdAt: "createdAt",
                updatedAt: "updatedAt",
            },
        }
    );

    const User = mongoose.model("user", userSchema);

    module.exports.hashPassword = async (password) => {
        try {
            const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10); // 10 rounds
            return await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
        } catch (error) {
            throw new Error("Hashing failed", error);
        }
    };

    module.exports = User;
```

and my `user.controller.js` file looks like this:

```
    const Joi = require("joi");
    require("dotenv").config();
    const { v4: uuid } = require("uuid");

    const { sendEmail } = require("./helpers/mailer");
    const User = require("./user.model");

    //Validate user schema
    const userSchema = Joi.object().keys({
    email: Joi.string().email({ minDomainSegments: 2 }),
    password: Joi.string().required().min(4),
    confirmPassword: Joi.string().valid(Joi.ref("password")).required(),
    });

    exports.Signup = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const result = userSchema.validate(req.body);
        if (result.error) {
        console.log(result.error.message);
        return res.json({
            error: true,
            status: 400,
            message: result.error.message,
        });
        }

        //Check if the email has been already registered.
        var user = await User.findOne({
        email: result.value.email,
        });

        if (user) {
        return res.json({
            error: true,
            message: "Email is already in use",
        });
        }
        
        const hashPassword = await User.hashPassword(result.value.password);

        const id = uuid(); //Generate unique id for the user.
        result.value.userId = id;

    //remove the confirmPassword field from the result as we dont need to save this in the db.
    delete result.value.confirmPassword;
    result.value.password = hashPassword;

        let code = Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 900000);  //Generate random 6 digit code.                             
        let expiry = Date.now() + 60 * 1000 * 15;  //Set expiry 15 mins ahead from now

        const sendCode = await sendEmail(result.value.email, code);

        if (sendCode.error) {
        return res.status(500).json({
            error: true,
            message: "Couldn't send verification email.",
        });
        }
        result.value.emailToken = code;
        result.value.emailTokenExpires = new Date(expiry);
        const newUser = new User(result.value);
        await newUser.save();

        return res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        message: "Registration Success",
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("signup-error", error);
        return res.status(500).json({
        error: true,
        message: "Cannot Register",
        });
    }
    };
```

Error displayed in terminal:

```
    Danilo@DANILO-PC D:\Meus Documentos\Área de Trabalho\api-auth-pokestore
    $ node app.js
    Server started listening on PORT : 5000
    Database connection Sucess.
    signup-error TypeError: User.hashPassword is not a function
        at exports.Signup (D:\Meus Documentos\Área de Trabalho\api-auth-pokestore\src\users\user.controller.js:39:37)
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
```

[image terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UhXU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this part of your code:

```js
module.exports.hashPassword = async (password) => { ... };

module.exports = User;
```

You're setting `hashPassword` in your exports, then completely replacing your exports with `User`. You probably wanted to do something like this instead:

```js
User.hashPassword = async (password) => { ... };

module.exports = User;
```

*or move your `module.exports.hashPassword = ...` so it's after the `module.exports = ...`.*